# MAAS node install shutdown error when installing from CD-ROM

Tags: server, virtualbox, maas

I am trying out the new MAAS tool on my laptop and have installed the MAAS server in a VirtualBox VM. Since the PXE boot option is not working for me in a virtualized enviornment I tried to install a node with the CD-ROM option instead.

I select the option "Multiple server install with MAAS" then it proceeds up to the option of entering the IP address of the MAAS server. I have MAAS already installed on another VM and provide the IP address of the MAAS server.

The problem is that immediately after the node shuts down without completing the install process. I tried to look in the MAAS server and the node is not registered there either. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reach the MAAS server IP from your client?

Comment: What versions or Virtualbox, pxeboot, and OS are you running as your host OS?  There was a known bug with PXE that got fixed a while back(involved a bunch of variables.  suffice it to say it's fixed)?  Also, are you using a NAT adapter for the network or bridged with a thin software router.  In the latter case it's easier to get PXE working in the virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

I deployed both physical servers (successfully) and on VirtualBox (failing).
The immediate shut down is the intended behavior. The problem with VirtualBox is that, once the installation process of the server is complete, the server should be able to wake-on-lan (optional), and PXE boot (required). I haven't figured out how to PXE boot in VirtualBox, unfortunately.
Anyway, your failure is not in the installation process. It's the PXE booting.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [Testing MAAS on edubuntu wiki](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/SecurityTeam/TestingMAAS), which gives instructions to test MAAS in virtual machines. There are some hints regarding PXE boot but with virt-manager instead of VirtualBox. It may help!

Comment: By the way, it looks like your question is linked to [MaaS Enlistment through 12.04 installation CD fails](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134164/maas-enlistment-through-12-04-installation-cd-fails)

Answer (score 1):

I have used

```
ethernet0.virtualDev = "vlance"
```

setting.

And at router edit

```
/etc/dnsmasq/dhcp.conf
```

add

```
dhcp-boot={pxeboot file}, {hostname of tftp server}, {ip address of tftpserver}
```

(dhcp-boot=10.10.10.50 - in my case)

then

```
/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

Voila!