# Is one node + MAAS possible?

Tags: maas

Presently I have two machines wanting to join a private cloud an hp i386 & dell
 amd64. Installing the MAAS in the dell and attempting to add the hp as a node yields

> Unable to create Node: Unknown problem encountered with the Cobbler server like:

- [MaaS Enlistment through 12.04 installation CD fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134164/maas-enlistment-through-12-04-installation-)

Installing the MAAS in the hp and attempting to add the dell as a node yields :
 Nodes have a status of "Commissioning" like:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS/Troubleshooting.

Do I need to install and configure other servers to the MAAS before attempting to
 add nodes? Kinda like what maxmid was hinting at in :
[Architecture diagram explaining the Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure with MAAS / Openstack architecture?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130139/architecture-diagram-explaining-the-ubuntu-cloud-infrastructure-with-maas-open)
 With comment:  Maybe a first step would be to list what is the role of each 10 machines of the Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure deployment with MAAS and Juju:

1. MAAS server
2. juju bootstrap node (Juju uses it to coordinate the services being deployed)
3. mysql
4. openstack's rabbitmq
5. openstack's keystone
6. openstack's nova-cloud-controller
7. openstack's nova-volume
8. openstack's nova-compute
9. openstack's glance
10. openstack's openstack-dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Check your date and time on the MAAS server and the node have a look at the bugs
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/maas/+bug/992075

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I don't have the time right now to go back into this but looking at :